# layout in nextjs (doc) doesn't seem to work

Tags: next.js13, web-frontend, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have layout.tsx page in root app folder. Its path is frontend/app/layout.tsx

```
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} mx-5`} >
        <Navbar />
        <main>
          {children}
        </main> 
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

And then I have the layout in folder which is authLayout. It's path is frontend/app/(auth)/layout.tsx. I also have two routes in auth folder login and register. To which I would like to implement authLayout so that I don't have navbar in login and register page

```
export default function AuthLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full flex-1 px-20 text-center bg-grey-400">
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Am I doing it the wrong way with using layout in the folder or my routing is wrong or the process I am trying to do is wrong?
P.S. I know the method of checking if it is logged in or not I want to know if its possible using layout.tsx

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but do you have the RootLayout and want to create another RootLayout within the group `(auth)` to override the external one? As far as I know, layouts are nested, so you can't do it this way. But you can create multiple RootLayouts by creating another group like `(other)`. [see doc about this!](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#creating-multiple-root-layouts)

Comment: Here the link [Creating multiple root layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#creating-multiple-root-layouts)